# Does "triangle" in English exclude degenerate triangles?

Tags: triangles, project-euler

Just for fun read few problems on the projeteuler.net website.

Number 276 found interesting:

> Consider the triangles with integer sides a, b and c with a ≤ b ≤ c.
>   An integer sided triangle (a,b,c) is called primitive if gcd(a,b,c)=1.
>   How many primitive integer sided triangles exist with a perimeter not
>   exceeding 10 000 000?

Question:

Does the definition "triangle" in English also enforces the following condition?

**a + b > c**

Comment: Yes. If it didn't, then $a$, $b$ and $c$ could not form a triangle.

Comment: It must hold that $a + b \geq c$. $a + b = c$ holds iff the triangle degenerates into a line (two points coincide). Usually, when one says triangle, one means a non-degenerate triangle.

Comment: @aelguindy so in this particular problem can I assume that we are talking about non-degenerate triangles?

Comment: @Dime: Absolutely you can assume non-degenerate.

Comment: Of course, the real place to ask what a Project Euler question means is on the Project Euler site, not here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*A CW answer to remove this question from the Unanswered queue.*

---

Yes, "triangle" can be taken to mean "non-degenerate triangle" unless *explicitly* stated otherwise. As far as I know, this convention is universal.

Answer (score 4):

In *some* mathematical English, a triangle means exactly what it did 2,300 years ago:

> "A triangle is plane figure bounded by three straight lines." (*A Text-book of Euclid's Elements*, Hall & Stevens, 1888).

This definition seems unclear.

But later, *Proposition 20* clarifies it (emphasis added):

> "Any two sides of a triangle are together ***greater*** than the other third side." (*ibid.*)

However, the articles https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_inequality and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normed_vector_space contradict one another: the latter includes *equality*.

But, I think, most (English) mathematicians would agree with the latter, and disagree with Euclid, and will allow degenerate triangles to partake in the so-called triangle *inequality*.

Comment: **Edit:** The two references to Hall & Stevens may be found for example at https://archive.org/details/textbookofeuclid00eucliala/page/36/mode/2up, pages 4 and 36, or at https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=mdp.39015064572400, pages 4 and 42.

Comment: **Edit:** The authors of the Wikipedia article argued among themselves as to whether the Triangle Inequality is an inequality: see https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Triangle_inequality&direction=prev&oldid=510838204.